# Generate jquery validation rules and messages from json data

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, validation, object

I've a built js form builder function which outputs form elements based on data from an external json file. In the json data it also data for validation rules and messages.

**Example data:**

```
"rows": [
[{
    "Name": "FirstName",
    "Description": "Enter your name",
    "IsRequired": true,
    "Datatype": "string",
    "Maxlength": 255,
    "InputLabel": "Name",
    "InputInitialValue": "",
    "InputSourceChannel": "constant",
    "FieldWidth": 170,
    "PlaceholderText": "Joe Blogs",
    "ValidationMessage": "Please provide your name"
}]
]
```

I'm looking to generate variables for rules and messages used by jQuery validate from data in the son file, and conditionally add validation methods such as email, max length etc dependant on values set in the json data.

For example, I'd like to add the `email: true` method to rules for the email input field as well as the `required: true` method (should that be set).

**Example expect result**

```
    FirstName: {
        required: true
      },
      LastName: {
        required: true
      },
      Title: {
        required: true,
        max-length: 50
      },
      Company: {
        required: true
      },
      Email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      Phone: {
        required: true, 
        phone: true
      }
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/onebitrocket/6d73jyen/

To add the `email: true` method required an if\else statement if zDatatype: email` matched a value in an array.
If i wanted to add in an additional methods such as maxlength it could get a little messy additional if statements.

Is there are way can concatenate all the required methods in to a variable and then call the variable in the object?

I think I'm correct in understanding that all conditional statements need to be done out side of the js

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using `$.extend` to construct a new object from unique objects for each validationRule type/required

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10892275/1376820

```
var validationRulesRequired = {},
    validationRulesType = {},
    validationRules;

$.each(jsonData.rows, function(key, value) {
    $.each(value, function(ikey, ivalue) {

        // generate validation messages
        if (ivalue.ValidationMessage) {
            validationMessages[ivalue.Name] = ivalue.ValidationMessage;
        }

        // generate validation rules
        if (ivalue.IsRequired) {
            var validationInputTypes = ['email', 'phone'];

            if ($.inArray(ivalue.Datatype, validationInputTypes) > -1) {
                validationRulesType[ivalue.Name] = {
                    [ivalue.Datatype]: true,
                };
            }
            validationRulesRequired[ivalue.Name] = {
                ['required']: true,
            };
        }
    });
});
var validationRules = $.extend(true, {}, validationRulesRequired, validationRulesType);

console.log(validationRules);
```

See updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/onebitrocket/6d73jyen/6/