# jQuery: Passing values to array without affecting others

Tags: jquery

I am using a tabs plugin which allows you to pass your default options for it's behavior.

```
$('#responsiveTabsDemo').responsiveTabs({
startCollapsed: 'accordion',
setHash: true
});
```

Inside the .js file:

```
var defaults = {

        active: null,
        event: 'click',
        disabled: [],
        collapsible: 'accordion',
        startCollapsed: false,
        rotate: false,
        setHash: false,
        animation: 'default',
        animationQueue: false,
        duration: 500,
        scrollToAccordion: false,
        scrollToAccordionOnLoad: true,
        scrollToAccordionOffset: 0,
        accordionTabElement: '<div></div>',
        activate: function(){},
        deactivate: function(){},
        load: function(){},
        activateState: function(){},
        classes: {
            tabStyle: 'j',
            stateDefault: 'j-tabs-state-default',
            stateActive: 'j-tabs-state-active',
            stateDisabled: 'j-tabs-state-disabled',
            stateExcluded: 'j-tabs-state-excluded',
            container: 'j-tabs',
            ul: 'j-tabs-nav',
            tab: 'j-tabs-tab',
            anchor: 'j-tabs-anchor ',
            panel: 'j-tabs-panel',
            accordionTitle: 'j-tabs-accordion-title '
        }
    };
```

So, by specifying any of these on the page, I can overwrite any of the defaults.

However, I would like to overwrite some of the default values for `classes`. I tried:

```
$('#responsiveTabsDemo').responsiveTabs({

    startCollapsed: 'accordion',
    setHash: true,
    classes: {
      tabStyle: 'r'
    }

});
```

...but this removes all the other values for `classes`.

How can I pass just one value to this array without wiping out all the others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the original plugin is using `jQuery.extend()` to merge 2 objects, but it is not doing recursive copy. So basically, you can achieve what you need by replacing [this line of code](https://github.com/jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs/blob/master/js/jquery.responsiveTabs.js#L53) in the plugin, with this:

```
this.options = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);
```

Fork the project on GitHub and send a pull request with a change to the author. Get the functionality you need, plus some benefit to the open source community :)

Comment: Came to same solution, credits to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892222/is-there-are-proper-way-to-extend-a-nested-properties-in-jquery#10892275).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking the documentation for this particular plug-it to see if it has functionality that would allow you to add a single class (in addition to the defaults). Otherwise, you could explicitly pass in the defaults as well as your specific class :

```
classes: {
        tabStyle: 'r',
        stateDefault: 'j-tabs-state-default',
        stateActive: 'j-tabs-state-active',
        stateDisabled: 'j-tabs-state-disabled',
        stateExcluded: 'j-tabs-state-excluded',
        container: 'j-tabs',
        ul: 'j-tabs-nav',
        tab: 'j-tabs-tab',
        anchor: 'j-tabs-anchor ',
        panel: 'j-tabs-panel',
        accordionTitle: 'j-tabs-accordion-title '
}
```

A cursory glance at [the source](https://github.com/jellekralt/Responsive-Tabs/blob/master/js/jquery.responsiveTabs.js) doesn't appear to have this functionality, but the plug-in itself looks like it is open-source, so you could probably extend this quite easily if you so desired.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, this plug-in does not allow for that, which is why I am trying to fudge it myself. I was trying to avoid having to explicitly pass all the defaults myself, but if I have to, then I have to I suppose.